# Story about people living in a cave and not wanting to leave and explore

Tags: identification-request, allegory

I have a vague memory of a story where a tribe of some sort lives in a cave for generations, and never leaves because they have access to food and water. One time, someone (it may have been a child; not sure) leaves the cave and sees the world, and returns and tells everyone they need to leave the cave and experience the world, which was full of wonders that would have improved everyone's lives, but everyone else disagrees because the cave has their essentials, and they don't want to "waste" resources exploring a dangerous unknown while they have their own problems to worry about in the cave.

Again, this story is just a vague memory and I definitely could've misremembered large parts of the story, but the "lesson" for me had always been that you cannot use "we have our own problems to worry about here" as an excuse to not explore the unknown, because the unknown can (and has) done a lot to improve the quality of life for humanity (I usually used this story to explain why space exploration is important).

After some research I thought I may just be thinking about Plato's Allegory of the Cave, but, although there are a lot of similarities, there are also a couple differences (i.e a large group of people, instead of prisoners), and the "moral" of the story seems to be quite different from that of the Allegory of the Cave (which, from what I can gather, is more about perspectives shaping your view of the world).

I honestly may have just warped the Allegory of the Cave into my own interpretation after many years, so if no one can find an alternative, I'll just assume that. If not though, what story is behind my vague memory?

Comment: Could it be the story described in 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthem_(novella) ?

Comment: @kimchilover hmm I don’t think so, although that story looks interesting!

Comment: Maybe related to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226580/looking-for-ya-short-story-about-boy-who-finds-family-living-in-cave-from-altern)?